# How to use the 'alias' property in the search schema

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, content-search-web-part

I am trying a simple content query to roll up blogs.

I am using the 2 lines, first line for title (working) and second line for Published ( = publisheddate).

I have mapped ows_publisheddate to refinabledate19 and in the alias empty field I typed an easy to remember equal term like PublishedDateBlog.

Not only it does not pull the date by putting Refinabledate19 field as a second field, but my alias PublishedDateBlog does not show in the list of fields available. Even typing, the date is not pulled.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After making these schema changes, did you initiate a reindex on the site(s) where you want to use these refiners and aliases?

Comment: no, I used to remember that on premise this was not needed, is it needed for SP online?

Comment: in my experience, yes, any schema changes need a site reindex to pick it up

Comment: If the blogs are subsites to one site collection, do i have to start the reindex on every single subsite or the site collection is enough?

Comment: at the site collection root should suffice to update the schema, but you may need to do it in the subsites

Comment: still the 'alias' does not show up in the mapping list in the query web part, should i type it instead of selecting?